# Cannot estimate standard errors associated with Vegan function fisher.alpha

Tags: r, vegan

All the documents associated with `BiodiversityR` and Vegan suggest that argument `se=TRUE` can be used to estimate standard errors on calculation of fisher's alpha diversity index. But I can't seem to get these values in the output? Any body knowns of any associated bug?

I tried :

```
fisher.alpha(x,MARGIN=1,se=TRUE)
```

and also, `fisherfit(x)`

The output for both gives me an estimate of alpha, but no standard errors. My community data frame is too large to be loaded here, but it is in the standard format as required by these functions.

- Vegan version 2.4.2

Comment: I just found out the estimation of standard errors for alpha has been removed by the authors 4 years ago, since the values of alpha are non-normal and skewed so standard errors are of not much use.

Answer (score 1):

The standard errors were not removed because they were non-normal and skewed, but because I was not convinced that they were correct. (There is nothing wrong in being non-Normal and skewed.). If you want to play with those standard errors, you can get **vegan** version 2.0-9 from the CRAN archive, or revert commit 2c44f2b7c9 in the github tree of **vegan**. However, you should verify the correctness of those standard errors yourself: they may be OK, but I do not know, and therefore I removed them.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. Will look it up.